# Invalid src prop in Next.js

Tags: javascript, next.js

Error: Invalid src prop (https://scontent-atl3-2.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.30497-1/c29.0.100.100a/p100x100/84628273_176159830277856_972693363922829312_n.jpg?_nc_cat=1&ccb=1-4&_nc_sid=12b3be&_nc_ohc=GsA3y-ZkuUoAX_VFkof&_nc_ht=scontent-atl3-2.xx&edm=AP4hL3IEAAAA&oh=19bbbd2923855115071affa90dc53b68&oe=6138E675) on `next/image`, hostname "scontent-atl3-2.xx.fbcdn.net" is not configured under images in your `next.config.js`

See more info: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-image-unconfigured-host

Answer (score 1):

All you need to is add to add the hostname in the error code to next.config.js

```
hostname "scontent-atl3-2.xx.fbcdn.net" is not configured under images in your next.config.js
```

Open your next.config.js, add the following under images.domains. Do this for any domain, mind you don't add 'www', 'http' or 'https'.

```
images: {
    domains: ["scontent-atl3-2.xx.fbcdn.net"],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Possible Solution: Remove Bundle Analyzer

Howdy devs,

After painstaking hours of messing with this, the problem wasn't the `domains:` area of the `next.config` file, it was a problem created by adding the`@next/bundle-analyzer` to the App ([this pkg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@next/bundle-analyzer)).

I don't know exactly what made things break, but our App is running Next v12.2.3 and it's possible that the bundle analyzer and our version of Next weren't playing nicely together.

So, I removed it and this error went away.